# VFP - Creating Project & exe build problems

Tags: build, project, exe, visual-foxpro

I have an application that consists of:

- 1 program file
- 6 main forms including the main menu
- 5 search forms in every other form
- A few reports in each form

I'm trying to build an .exe file, using these forms and reports. When I run my program from within the FoxPro IDE it works perfectly, but when I create an .exe file, it gives me a lot of problems.

Can someone tell me step by step how to do this so that my program can be run on another computer without FoxPro?

Comment: What type of problems... Syntax crashes, forms not staying displayed when expecting modal, procedures not being seen as you might anticipate???

Comment: @ DRapp well, before it didn't give me this problem,but now when i try to build it says "cannot find visual class library_FRAMWK" but when it did build before some icons would be missing, there'd be an ugly menu at the windowhead. lastly, the main menu has access to all the other forms, entering them is no problem, but when exiting them it should show the main menu again but it just says "main menu object not found" for some reason when i run my program (before building) from the main_menu.sct, it works. but when i run it from my main.prg file it gives me this problem. any ideas good sir? :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have paths to your objects in SET PATH TO ....